# Get file's modified date with condition - Batch Windows

Tags: windows, date, batch-file, if-statement

I have a `file.txt` in `Windows` and I would like to check if the file modified date is equal to some date with a `if statement`.

It will check in a `batch file`.

This is the idea to get de date:

```
for %a in (file.txt) do set FileDate=%~ta
```

But I need that with a condition and if the condition is true, It will execute a sqlcmd command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try that :

```
set date_today=%date:~0,2%/%date:~3,2%/%date:~6,4%

for %%x in ("your_file.txt") do set date_of_file=%%~tx

IF %date_of_file:~0, 10% == %date_today% goto same
goto notsame

:same
your sqlcmd command

:notsame
another thing
```

Of course, you will modify the %date_today% to the date you want.

Comment: Thanks, that's the idea ! What is the meaning of %%~tx ?

Comment: How can I add more conditions in the If statement?

Comment: `%%~t` represents the date/time of your variable, which is here 'x'. So  you have `%%~tx` but you could have anything else than x if you change your `for %%x`.

The %% is used in batch scripts; for simple commands in cmd.exe, you can use just one %

PS : Have a look here for precisions on what I have said, you will understand better the usage of the for command : http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html

Comment: If you want more than one condition in your IF statement, you have to write multiple IF statement one after the other. Example :

`IF NOT _condition_ goto next`  
`IF NOT _another condition_ goto next`  
`IF NOT _yet another condition_ goto next`

Return to line after each goto statement (I don't know how to do that in comments...)

Comment: It give me an error in the line: `for %%x in ("your_file.txt") do set date_of_file=%%~tx'` It doesn't return me a date.

Comment: Because I use this: `for %%x in (%file%) do set date_of_file=%%~tx'`

Comment: Yes, use `for %%x in ("%file%") do set date_of_file=%%~tx`.
You forgot the " ".

Comment: Thanks, was that !. Could do I get the time with hour? I'm looking for the website that you posted it and it say `Display the date/time of %1` but not how.

Comment: Yes you can. You have to play with this parameter : `IF %date_of_file:~0, 10%`. The '0' means you start at the position 0 (which is actually the first character of your variable), the '10' means you stop checking the content of the variable after the 10th character. Your time is hidden after the 10th character, so try something like `%date_of_file:~0,16%`, maybe less or more. In the case you just want the time, you can try something like `%date_of_file:~10,16%` (maybe not exactly those numbers). Is that OK ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are expecting to do is not really clear to me.

Does your file.sql contain a query which just returns one line with one date ?

So I think you should execute the file.sql (with some sqlcmd) and then get the output of the query, and finally do your comparison with an IF statement in your batch file. I certainly could help you but I'm not sure of what you want.

Comment: Sorry. No, file.sql is an example. Could be file.txt or file.x. It is indifferent

Comment: Ok, then could this file contain more than one date ? Moreover, I think the date should be in a normalized form (MM/JJ/AAAA) if you want your batch understand your date

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstand something I believe. Does your file contain a date or you want the date of that file ?

Comment: I want the the of that file.